# CakePHP is not displaying data from right table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am trying to display data from table games_reviews but instead I am getting data from table games, below is the controller I am using

```
class GamesReviewsController extends AppController {

 var $uses = array('Game', 'GamesVideo', 'games_reviews', 'GamesVideosType', 'GamesRewiewTypes','GamesGenre','User');


public function view() {
    //$this->layout = 'pages';
    $this->set('columns', 1);
    $url = $this->params['game_url'];
    $game = $this->Game->findByUrl($url);
    //render not found

    $videos = Set::combine($game['GamesVideo'], '{n}.id', '{n}', '{n}.position');
    if (!empty($game['Game']['amazon_iframe'])) {
        $this->set('xtraDiv', array('Buy Game' => array('type' => 'iframe', 'content' => $game['Game']['amazon_iframe'])));
    }
    $this->set('game', $game);
    $this->set('videos', $videos);



}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove the $uses array, this will not be required.

You will also probably want to use the `Containable` behavior for your models.

Anyhow, in the controller, your code would look like this:

```
$conditions = array('url' => $url);
$gamesReviews = $this->GamesReview->find('first', compact('conditions'));
```

I would suggest you take the time to re-read the CakePHP Cookbook, understanding it will greatly help.